# Is there a difference between subprocess.call() and subprocess.Popen.communicate()?

Tags: python, subprocess

On python 2.7, I used `subprocess.call(my_cmd)` when running a shell command.

However, I needed to check outputs of those commands, so I replaced them with `subprocess.Popen.communicate()`.

```
    command_line_process = subprocess.Popen(my_cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    process_stdout, process_stderr = command_line_process.communicate()
    logging.info(process_stdout)
    logging.info(process_stderr)
```

Is there a difference between the two methods other than the latter one can print outputs?

I wonder whether it'd be okay to replace all `subprocess.call()` with `subprocess.Popen.communicate()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the documentation already tells you, you want to avoid `Popen` whenever you can.

The `subprocess.check_output()` function in Python 2.7 lets you retrieve the output from the subprocess, but otherwise works basically like `check_call()` (which in turn differs from `call` only in that it will raise an exception if the subprocess fails, which is something you usually want and need).

The case for `Popen` is that it enables you to build new high-level functions like these if you need to (like also then `subprocess.run()` in Python 3.5+ which is rather more versatile, and basically subsumes the functionality of all the above three).  They all use `Popen` under the hood, but it is finicky and requires you to take care of several details related to managing the subprocess object if you use it directly; those higher-level functions already do those things for you.

Common cases where you do need `Popen` is if you want the subprocess to run in parallel with your main Python script. There is no simple library function which does this for you.

Comment: For much more on the topic, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python/51950538#51950538

Answer (score 1):

If you check inside the source code, which you have on your system, you'll see that `subprocess.call` is implemented by calling `subprocess.Popen.wait`.  Virtually everything in that module is actually implemented in terms of `subprocess.Popen`.